# Creating groups by sorting method in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have to swap the elements of the array so that I get groups. For example, the first element with uniqueID and empty parentDocId goes first, and then the elements with parentDocId equal to uniqueID of the first element. Elements with an empty parentDocId without a parent uniqueID should be at the bottom.

Here's an example of what I expect`

```js
[
    {
      name: 9,
      uniqueID: '22222',
      parentDocId: '',
    },
    {
      name: 11,
      uniqueID: '3463452345',
      parentDocId: '22222',
    },
    {
      name: 15,
      uniqueID: '3333',
      parentDocId: '',
    },
    {
      name: 19,
      uniqueID: '234235346',
      parentDocId: '3333',
    },
    {
      name: 346345,
      uniqueID: '11111',
      parentDocId: '',
    },
    {
      name: 7,
      uniqueID: '456456456',
      parentDocId: '11111',
    },
    {
      name: 55,
      uniqueID: '346345345',
      parentDocId: '',
    },
    {
      name: 77,
      uniqueID: '568567568567',
      parentDocId: '',
    },
  ];
```

And an example of what I get

```js
[
    {
        "name": 55,
        "uniqueID": "346345345",
        "parentDocId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": 77,
        "uniqueID": "568567568567",
        "parentDocId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": 7,
        "uniqueID": "456456456",
        "parentDocId": "11111"
    },
    {
        "name": 346345,
        "uniqueID": "11111",
        "parentDocId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": 19,
        "uniqueID": "234235346",
        "parentDocId": "3333"
    },
    {
        "name": 15,
        "uniqueID": "3333",
        "parentDocId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": 11,
        "uniqueID": "3463452345",
        "parentDocId": "22222"
    },
    {
        "name": 9,
        "uniqueID": "22222",
        "parentDocId": ""
    }
]
```

This my code

```js
items.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.parentDocId === b.uniqueID) {
      return -1;
    } else if (b.parentDocId === a.uniqueID) {
      return 1;
    } else if (a.parentDocId === '' && b.parentDocId !== '') {
      return -1;
    } else if (a.parentDocId !== '' && b.parentDocId === '') {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to follow. What is exactly the issue? What is a *"first element"*? What makes it *"first"*?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, In my first example, the first element of the array is an object with the uniqueID property: '22222'. This is the parent. And behind it is an object with property parentDocId: '22222' which is its child. After the object with property uniqueID: '3333', there should be objects with property parentDocId: '3333'. But I get a different result in my sorting in the example below.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the problem right. This might be a possible solution.

```js
let items = [
    {
        "name": 55,
        "uniqueID": "346345345",
        "parentDocId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": 77,
        "uniqueID": "568567568567",
        "parentDocId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": 7,
        "uniqueID": "456456456",
        "parentDocId": "11111"
    },
    {
        "name": 346345,
        "uniqueID": "11111",
        "parentDocId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": 19,
        "uniqueID": "234235346",
        "parentDocId": "3333"
    },
    {
        "name": 15,
        "uniqueID": "3333",
        "parentDocId": ""
    },
    {
        "name": 11,
        "uniqueID": "3463452345",
        "parentDocId": "22222"
    },
    {
        "name": 9,
        "uniqueID": "22222",
        "parentDocId": ""
    }
]

let sortedArrays = [];

items.forEach(object=>{
   if(!object.parentDocId){
     sortedArrays.push([object]);
    
    }

})

sortedArrays.forEach(arg=>{

  items.forEach(object=>{
    if(arg.slice(-1)[0].uniqueID==object.parentDocId){
     
      arg.push(object)
     }
  })
})
let flatArray = sortedArrays.flat(1)
console.log(flatArray)
```

Comment: thank you. but only one sort function has to be used for this